# How to read particular row from groupby dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x

I am preprocessing my data about car sales where lots of used cars price is 0. I want to replace 0 value with the mean price value of similar kind of cars.

Here, I have found mean values for each car with groupby function:

```py
df2= df1.groupby(['car','body','year','engV'])['price'].mean()
```

This is my dataframe extracted from actual data with price is zero
`rep_price=df[df['price']==0]`

I want to assign mean price value from `df2['Land Rover']` to `rep_price['Land Rover']` which is 0

Comment: Refer [how to create minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not sure about the columns you have in those dataframes I'm gonna take a wild guess to try to give you a head start, let's say 'Land Rover' is a value in a column called 'Car_Type' in df1, and then you grouped your data like this:

```
df2= df1.groupby(['Car_Type'])['price'].mean()
```

In that case something like this should cover your need:

```
df1.loc[df1['Car_Type']=='Land Rover','price'] = df2['Land Rover']
```